# Send HTML data from a form into a JSON file (Ajax/Jquery)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

I've never done this before and I'm not too experienced with Ajax. WHat I want to do, I believe is fairly simple.

I want to take the data from this form:

```
 <form action="/comics.json" method="post" class="admin__add">
        <label for="admin__id">ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__id">
        <label for="admin__price">Price</label>
        <input type="number" class="admin__price">
        <label for="admin__url">URL</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__url">
        <label for="admin__data-item-description">Data-item-descriptin</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__data-item-description">
        <label for="admin__data-item-name">data-item-name</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__data-item-name">
        <label for="admin__year">year</label>
        <input type="number" class="admin__year">
        <label for="admin__issue">issue</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__issue">
        <label for="admin__series">series</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__series">
        <label for="admin__type">type</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__type">
        <label for="admin__label">label</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__label">
        <label for="admin__sale-price">sale-price</label>
        <input type="number" class="admin__sale-price">
        <label for="admin__publisher">publisher</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__publisher">
        <label for="admin__extra">extra</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__extra">
        <label for="admin__run">run?</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__run">
        <label for="admin__weight">weight</label>
        <input type="number" class="admin__weight">
        <label for="admin__stock">stock</label>
        <input type="number" class="admin__stock">
        <label for="admin__allowOutOfStockPurchases">allowOutOfStockPurchases</label>
        <input type="text" class="admin__allowOutOfStockPurchases">
        <button class="admin__submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
```

And add it into my Json file which is structured like this:

```
{
    "id" : "crossedonehundred9",
    "price" : "2.99",
    "url" : "/",
    "data-item-description" : "Crossed One Hundred run (32 books)",
    "data-item-image" : "/thumbnails/Fantasy Road new and preowned comic book sales - pressing and cleaning service at fantasy road - Crossed One Hundred 9.jpg",
    "data-item-name" : "Crossed One Hundred full run",
    "year" : "2012",
    "issue" : "9",
    "series" : "Crossed One Hundred",
    "type" : "",
    "label" : "",
    "sale-price" : "",
    "publisher" : "Avatar",
    "extra" : "",
    "enlarge" : "/img/Fantasy Road new and preowned comic book sales - pressing and cleaning service at fantasy road - Crossed One Hundred 9.jpeg",
    "run" : "",
    "dimensions" : {
        "weight" : "100"
    },
    "stock" : 1,
    "allowOutOfStockPurchases" : false
}
```

So far I've got this code, but I have 0 idea what I'm doing and I know its completely wrong.

```
$("admin__submit").click(function(){
var id = $('.admin__id');
var price = $('.admin__price');
var url = $('.admin__url');
var data1 = $('.admin__data-item-description');
var data2 = $('.admin__data-item-name');
var year = $('.admin__year');
var issue = $('.admin__issue');
var series = $('.admin__series');
var type = $('.admin__type');
var label = $('.admin__label');
var price = $('.admin__sale-price');
var publisher = $('.admin__publisher');
var extra = $('.admin__extra');
var run = $('.admin__run');
var weight = $('.admin__weight');
var stock = $('.admin__stock');
var allowOutOfStockPurchases = $('.admin__allowOutOfStockPurchases');


$.post("comics.json",
{
    "id" : '"' + id + '"',
    "price" : '"' + price + '"',
    "url" : "/",
    "data-item-description" : '"' + data1 + '"',
    "data-item-image" : '"' + url + '"',
    "data-item-name" : '"' + data2 + '"',
    "year" : '"' + year + '"',
    "issue" : '"' + issue + '"',
    "series" : '"' + series + '"',
    "type" : '"' + type + '"',
    "label" : '"' + label + '"',
    "sale-price" : '"' + sale-price + '"',
    "publisher" : '"' + publisher + '"',
    "extra" : '"' + extra + '"',
    "run" : '"' + run + '"',
    "dimensions" : {
        "weight" : '"' + weight + '"'
    },
    "stock" : stock,
    "allowOutOfStockPurchases" : allowOutOfStockPurchases
},
function(data, status){
  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add **.val()** for each of your inputs.

```
var price = $('.admin__price');
```

Here you made a reference to your input and saved it in variable price. So whenever you need to get its value you will call **.val()** on it

```
$.post("comics.json",
{
    "id" :  id.val() ,
    "price" :  price.val(),
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for that - When I click the submit button, I still get -

This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405

Comment: That is you are trying to send that data to page that does not exist. You are targeting "comics.json" there should be path to a server request you want to targer

Comment: Ah, I understand. I've now changed "comics.json" to "/comics.json" And I'm still getting the same error - is this not what you meant? The Json file is located at root

Comment: Ajax is used for sending to server not for sending to file. .json is a file not a server request

Comment: Ah I see. I think I may have wasted my time then, as my website doesn't have a back end. Is there any way to update the Json file from an HTML form without a back end?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't without a backend, might be that there are some third-party solutions that can help you work around this in some way, but most probably you would have to pay or something like that. It would surely be better and cheaper to build backend for yourself if this feature is a must